# double space gets automatically replaced with single

Tags: csh

I have s file with the following commands in a file.

```
#!/bin/csh -f
echo "test  test"  //echo test [dobule space] test
set a = "test  test"  //set a = test [dobule space] test
echo $a
```

**Output is as follows.**

*test [dobule space] test*

*test [single space] test*

How does the double space get replaced with a single space when I set value to a?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: yep, didn't notice..

Comment: @AvinashRaj that's because of a misleading title. Fixed that.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev it's because you didn't read the question properly. Nothing to do with the title.

Comment: @arco444 the title needs to reflect the essence of the question. The current one reads as a grammatically incorrect "automatically replace double space with single".

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev - nope, the word is "replaces" which is perfectly fine. If it was as you say _then_ it would be incorrect.

Comment: @arco444 Even if it's correct, it *looks very much like* incorrect. The meaning must be made clear beyond grammatical peculiarities since incorrect grammar is very common on this site. As it is now, I stand by my downvote for this reason.

Comment: @acro444 & ivan_pozdeev, It doesnt make sense, criticizing me, when you don't post an answer to my question. I dont care you downvote or upvote. All I need is to get a solution to my problem.

Comment: @Roni you did see how many people misinterpreted your question. If you want correct answers, ask correct questions.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I'm a newbie in shell commands. :)

Comment: @Roni I wasn't criticising you, quite the opposite. Seems everybody should be reading everything more carefully today!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How does the double space get replaced with a single space when I set value to a?

No it doesn't get replaced by single space. It is because you didn't use quotes in your `echo`. Use:

```
echo "$a"
```

to get double spaced string.

Shell by default trims multiple white-spaces into a single space if you don't quote your variables. Even this will be single space:

```
s='a     b'
echo $s
a b
```

But with quotes:

```
echo "$s"
a     b
```

---

**EDIT:** Based on comments below you can do this in csh:

```
set QUERY = "select p.path from path p, file f where p.pathid=f.pathid and f.fileid=1234"
set dir = "`/usr/etc/venture/bin/mysql -BN -uroot -***** ****-e '$QUERY'`"
echo "$dir"
```

Comment: Ok. And to my question, your answer is exactly correct. Appreciated. But my real problem is something different then.

Comment: Check my EDIT section, may be that will help. (Basically use quotes in `set dir` also).

Answer (score 0):

In `bash`, any runs of whitespace characters on the command line are by default replaced by a single space unless the value is quoted.

The [`bash` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) tells this, but in a very roundabout way:

"Quoting" section:

> Enclosing characters in single quotes preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes.
>
> Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of $, `, \, and, when history expansion is enabled, !

...Which implies whitespace characters! Since, as it turns out, they are "special":

"Word splitting" section:

> If **IFS** is unset, or its value is exactly `<space><tab><newline>`, the default, then sequences of `<space>`, `<tab>`, and `<newline>` at the beginning and end of the results of the previous expansions are ignored, and any sequence of **IFS** characters not at the beginning or end serves to delimit words.

Comment: But this is csh not BASH

Comment: <del>Does anyone still write in `csh`?</del> I mean, using `csh` is very uncommon and wasn't emphasized at all so that slipped by me.

Comment: `csh` is specified both in the question tag and the shebang in the code snippet provided by OP

Comment: @arco444 To be fair i only removed the bash tag a few minutes before this answer was posted.

Comment: @JID and to be fair the `csh` tag and shebang (which, let's be honest, really does give the game away) were already present at that point

Comment: @arco444 I was just trying to point out where the confusion could have come from, OP may have wanted a solution in both (unlikely) but still they didn't really specify.

Comment: Whitespace characters are only special in the sense that whitespace is whitespace, however many spaces, tabs, newlines (?) they consists of, its only a whitespace. It's a separator, and when printed it gets printed as a single space.